# AWS Lambda function with placeholders

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am working on AWS Lambda function for my python function. I have a python function that calls an IAM policy form a file and populates it using the function. This is my function, name of the file is template_utils.py":

```
import sys
import json
import time 
import meta_templates
from jinja2 import Template
def lambda_handler(event,context):
  template_data = {}
  template_data["region"] = event.get('region')
  template_data["instance_types"] = event.get('instance_type')
  template_data["ebs_volume_size"] = event.get('ebs_volume_size')
  template_data["meta_template_name"] = event.get('meta_template_name')

  meta_template_dict = getattr(meta_templates, template_data["meta_template_name"])
  meta_template_json = json.dumps(meta_template_dict)
  template_json = Template(meta_template_json).render(template_data)
  return template_json  

template_json = lambda_handler(
  region="us-east-2",
  instance_type="t2.micro",
  ebs_volume_size="20",
  meta_template_name="ec2_policy_meta_template"
)

print(template_json)
```

This is my policy file named "meta_templates.py"

```
import json
from jinja2 import Template
ec2_policy_meta_template = { 
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::instance/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::network-interface/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::key-pair/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::security-group/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::subnet/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::volume/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::image/ami-*"
                ],
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:NumericLessThanEquals": {
                        "ec2:VolumeSize": "{{ebs_volume_size}}"
                    },
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:InstanceType": "{{instance_type}}"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                    "ec2:StartInstances",
                    "ec2:StopInstances"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::instance/*",
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:InstanceType": "{{instance_type}}"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:Describe*",
                    "ec2:GetConsole*",
                    "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                    "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
                    "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                    "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                    "ec2:CreateKeyPair"
                ],
                "Resource": "*",
                "Condition": {
                    "DateGreaterThan": {
                        "aws:CurrentTime": "{{start_time}}"
                    },
                    "DateLessThanEquals": {
                        "aws:CurrentTime": "{{end_time}}"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to create a lambda handler that does the same thing with the function "template_utils.py".I'm new to this not sure how to proceed with it.I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pranay/Desktop/work/lambda_handler.py", line 18, in <module>
    template_json = lambda_handler(
TypeError: lambda_handler() got an unexpected keyword argument 'region'
```

Comment: `lambda_handler` expects a event and context, you give it a region - that is not going to work obviously.

Comment: Removed all AWS related tags since this is not AWS specific but a regular python problem?

Comment: this is an aws-lambda function so I will be using it to invoke functions on AWS, so I reckoned including those tags might give a better outreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, providing that you are passing the correct data in the event.

```
import json


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    template_data = {}
    region = event.get('region')
    instance_type = event.get('instance_type')
    ebs_volume_size = event.get('ebs_volume_size')
    start_time = event.get('start_time')
    end_time = event.get('end_time')

    ec2_policy_meta_template = { 
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
              {
                  "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
                  "Resource": [
                      "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::instance/*",
                      "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::network-interface/*",
                      "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::key-pair/*",
                      "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::security-group/*",
                      "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::subnet/*",
                      "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::volume/*",
                      "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::image/ami-*"
                  ],
                  "Condition": {
                      "ForAllValues:NumericLessThanEquals": {
                          "ec2:VolumeSize": "{{ebs_volume_size}}"
                      },
                      "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                          "ec2:InstanceType": "{{instance_type}}"
                      }
                  }
              },
              {
                  "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                      "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                      "ec2:StartInstances",
                      "ec2:StopInstances"
                  ],
                  "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::instance/*",
                  "Condition": {
                      "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                          "ec2:InstanceType": "{{instance_type}}"
                      }
                  }
              },
              {
                  "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                      "ec2:Describe*",
                      "ec2:GetConsole*",
                      "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                      "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
                      "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                      "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                      "ec2:CreateKeyPair"
                  ],
                  "Resource": "*",
                  "Condition": {
                      "DateGreaterThan": {
                          "aws:CurrentTime": "{{start_time}}"
                      },
                      "DateLessThanEquals": {
                          "aws:CurrentTime": "{{end_time}}"
                      }
                  }
              }
          ]
      }
      
    json_data = json.dumps(ec2_policy_meta_template)

    # Update resources with a string replacement
    json_data = json_data.replace("{{region}}", region)
    json_data = json_data.replace("{{instance_type}}", instance_type)
    json_data = json_data.replace("{{ebs_volume_size}}", ebs_volume_size)
    json_data = json_data.replace("{{start_time}}", start_time)
    json_data = json_data.replace("{{end_time}}", end_time)
    
    return json_data
```

This example uses only Python (no third party libraries) it's not the most elegant solution but its simple. If you want to create additional replacements, just add some additional tags "{{some_text}}" and replace it as shown below.

Here is a test event that works from the lambda console.
[image: Test Event]

And here is an example of a working invocation
[image: working invocation returning json]

Comment: The appilcation is python based and hence we need to use Boto and I am very new to python so it is taking me a little while to understand,your program works great but this does not give the output in json format what should I be printing here.TIA.

Comment: Also, the values for region, instance_type and ebs_volume needs to be in the function. I can't get rid of that part.

Comment: What are you intending to use boto for? The question you've asked has no boto related requirements, you're simply parsing a template by providing values to it through an event.

A lambda handler can only accept two parameters, you can't change that https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html. Even if you could, the service will only pass two parameters to it.

The two parameters are essentially two dictionaries, in which you're accessing the values by using event.get('region') etc..

Comment: My query is not boto related I was just explaining why I am not using terraform, I am just not sure how to fill the placeholders in the template from the lambda function.

Comment: Ok no worries, what you're trying to do is relatively simple but using lambda for this task has a steeper learning curve. For starters, the Jinja2 library isn't included in the lambda environment so you will need to learn how to package and zip 3rd party libraries if you want to use lambda. If you want a simple solution, I can adjust my previous answer to use f-strings, this will allow you to create a template within the function and parameters will come from the event (region, instance_types, etc).

Comment: Yeah I think f-strings is a better option for now, I think. Thanks a lot.

Comment: whiile running it in the console I get the output "{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}" I don't know why I have saved everything where it should be

Comment: That's because you didn't do a deploy after you updated the code.

Comment: Can you guide me on how to zip the files like what should be in my zip folder, and after that can I just upload the folder and start writing the lambda function. I'm sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: For my particular use-case should I write a lambda function that will call my python function?

Comment: Its quite a detailed process but very well documented, I would suggest having a read of this page from the AWS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html